# Receiving 403 error with Users.Messages.Send in Gmail API

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api

I'm trying to call Send on the GmailService from a C# .NET MVC app. and I keep getting a 403 error when I call send.

I've checked my scopes, the Gmail setup definitely has the Gmail API enabled, and my ClientID and ClientSecret are fresh.

```c#
var httpClient = new HttpClient{
  BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.googleapis.com")
};

var requestUrl = $"oauth2/v4/token?code={code}&client_id={ClientId}&client_secret={SecretKey}&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}&grant_type=authorization_code";

var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>{
  { "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }
};

var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUrl){Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict)};
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(req);
var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GmailToken>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
Session["user"] = token.AccessToken;

//var obj = await GetuserProfile(token.AccessToken);
var obj = await DoSendEmail(token);
```

```c#
public void DoSendEmail(GmailToken inToken) {
  const string fromAcct = "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com";

  TokenResponse token = new TokenResponse();
  token.AccessToken = inToken.AccessToken;
  token.ExpiresInSeconds = inToken.ExpiresIn;
  token.IdToken = inToken.IdToken;
  token.TokenType = inToken.TokenType;
  token.IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

  IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer {
    ClientSecrets = secrets,
    Scopes = SCOPES,
    ProjectId = "Xcent CP"
  });

  UserCredential credential = new UserCredential(flow, fromAcct, token);

  if (credential.Token.IsExpired(credential.Flow.Clock)) {
    bool success = credential.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result;
    if (!success) {
      throw new Exception("Could not refresh token");
    }
  }

  GmailService gs = null;
  try {
    gs = new GmailService(new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer() {
       ApplicationName = APP_NAME,
       HttpClientInitializer = credential
    });

    var mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(fromAcct);
    mailMessage.To.Add("XXXXXXXX@comcast.net");
    mailMessage.ReplyToList.Add(fromAcct);
    mailMessage.Subject = "Test email";
    mailMessage.Body = "<html><body>Hi <b>Lee</b>, this is <b>yet another</b> test message.</body></html>";
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

    var mimeMessage = MimeKit.MimeMessage.CreateFromMailMessage(mailMessage);

    var gmailMessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message {
      Raw = Encode(mimeMessage.ToString())
    };

    gs.Users.Messages.Send(gmailMessage, fromAcct).Execute();

  }
  catch (Exception ex) {
    throw ex;
  }
  finally {
    if (gs != null) {
      gs.Dispose();
    }
    gs = null;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure where to look...I've been through many many many online articles and tutorials, tried seemingly everything, and I'm still stuck with the 403 error. Help!

Thanks,
Lee

Comment: Is this all of your code? Where are you authenticating with Google's servers? If you check out the [developer's API reference for C#](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet) there is a guide on how to set up authentication with Google. What line of code is returning the 403 error?

Comment: Hi Rafa, the line that's failing is "gs.Users.Messages.Send(gmailMessage, fromAcct).Execute();". Not sure what you mean by authenticate...I have the following code:            Response.Redirect($"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={ClientId}&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}&state=abcdef");

Comment: You need to authenticate so that you can prove to Google that it is actually you that is authorising these actions and not someone else. Are you going to the link that you're getting in the Response.Redirect? You need to follow that URL and confirm you're happy for the program to run on your behalf.

Comment: The code that starts with "var httpClient" (the first block above) is where I'm handling the redirect. I'm getting a token back but that token doesn't seem to have the mail.google.com scope.

Comment: A line in your code is   `Scopes = SCOPES`. Where is `SCOPES` coming from? You need to define the scopes, something like:  `static string[] SCOPES = { GmailService.Scope.Gmail};` I suggest you to base your code on the template for the .NET Quickstart https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet and replace the request `UsersResource.LabelsResource.ListRequest request = service.Users.Labels.List("me");...` through your request: `Users.Messages.Send(...`

Comment: Hi  Ziganotschka,I do have a SCOPES definition...static public string[] SCOPES = { GmailService.Scope.MailGoogleCom, "email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send" };. Also, the .NET Quickstart uses a local and not http derived token.

Answer (score 1):

So after many hours spent looking at this I figured out the problem. My link to the Google login was this:

Response.Redirect($"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id={ClientId}&response_type=code&scope=openid%20email%20profile&redirect_uri={RedirectUrl}&state=abcdef");

"openid%20email%20profile" was the only scope I was specifying for the login, hence the 403 error about the scope I was using for the flow variable.

*phew!*